# How to align columns in bootstrap to center?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In the following code: I want to add columns dynamically. And thus the row can have none, single or at max four col-sm-3 columns in the row. No matter how many columns are there, the content should always appear in the middle.

```
      <div class="row">

          <div class="col col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                    <div class="servicesContent">

                        <img src="a.jpg" class="img-responsive" />

                        <p class="servicesContentTitle">lorem ipsum</p>

                    </div>
                </div>

          </div>
```

To achieve it, I have used the code below:

```
.row{
    text-align:center;
}
.col{
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

This does the job for three columns but when I have four col-sm-3 then it breaks down as you can see below:

[image]

What will be the correct css to align it perfectly at the center for any possible number of columns in the row.

Comment: Where? and how is it going to solve the issue?

Comment: can you add `margin:0` to `row` and `padding:0` to `col` and remove the style you have applied to the `col`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to set max-width for the columns. See below for an example

```
@media(min-width: 992px){
    .col{
        float:none;
        display:inline-block;
        max-width: 250px;
    }
}

@media(min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 992px){
    .col{
        float:none;
        display:inline-block;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be because the four objects are filling up the entire row (when the margins and padding is added). If you change the padding and/or margins of the columns you 'should' be able to remedy this issue.

Comment: I did try by making the margin and padding of columns to 0px but it didn't solve the problem.